# Extracting tables, lines, and coordinates from PDF using PDFSharp/C#

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I have several reports saved as PDF which contains several tables in between texts and images. I'm not sure if these tables are really tables or just lines. I tried to open these files using LibreOffice Writer and they were only lines but I'm still not sure if it is Writer's behavior on handling PDF's tables or just lines only.

How to make sure that these tables are really tables and how to extract them? If they were only lines, how to extract these lines and texts with their coordinates?

I'm using PDFSharp. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question but someone could need it

"Quite obvious" introduction:
PDF files are stream of graphics object (for example lines) and text. When the PDF is rendered the human eye understand that there are tables because of lines and text between them.

**The (my) solution**
Starting from a PDF reader (iTextSharp) you need to:
1. read the lines (hopefully only vertical and horizontal lines);
2. join the lines (a line of a table could be several lines, for example one per cell);
3. understand where the tables are (sometimes making some hypothesis based on your needs);
4. optionally find the text outside the tables (better to keep all the text) and insert it in paragraphs;
5. Insert text inside the cells of the table

If you need something already written to start from (working for my pdfs) you can find something here https://github.com/bubibubi/ExtractTablesFromPdf
It uses the GPL version of iTextSharp.
In this project there is the code to extract lines, boxes, tables and tables content.

Answer (score 0):

PDFsharp was not designed to extract text from PDF files.

In the PDFsharp forum you can find some code for that purpose:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=1603#p1603
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=4010#p4010

There are no tables in PDF. There are instructions that draw text, there are instructions that draw lines.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I can extract text already but how to extract data regarding those lines? Like their positions and text coordinates. The tables in the PDF file is quite hard to extract unless I have their coordinates because a single cell might contain multiple rows and opcodes of "TJ/Tj".

Comment: For a PDF page you get co-ordinates, Move instructions, Line instructions, Text instructions. If you "know" that there is a table then you can analyse the co-ordinates of the line instructions to find the dimensions of cells and then figure out which text belongs to which cells. If you can extract text already then extracting lines will just be "more of the same" and should be easy to implement. With kerning there may be several text instructions for a single word and many PDFtoDOC converters fail at this point.

Comment: I'm expecting it to be the same but I can't find the proper op code for the lines. Also the CString object doesn't have coordinates.